# When do we use web_set_timeout function in the loadrunner?

Tags: loadrunner

I have seen web_set_timeout function in some scripts. It limits the time for the response for the request. When do we use it?

Comment: What's your theory?  In two decades I have never had to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it to dynamically change the timeouts in the script, based on requirements that differ from step to step.

Typically used when accessing REST API's in a micro-service environment, and there are different NFR's for different services.

Another post for reference: http://overloaded.io/change-timeout-loadrunner